# Are some sounds more pleasing to the ear, like ㄴ and ㅁ?

Tags: spoken-korean, honorific, history-of-korean

I notice that many honorifics have similar consonant sounds when spoken. For example, the ~ㅂ/습니다 conjugation and the ~님 noun ending (e.g., in 선생님, 사장님, 아버님) have the ㄴ and ㅁ sounds when spoken.

Are some sounds more pleasing to the ear? Indeed to me the ㄴ and ㅁ consonants sound like honey, but could that be why the Korean language evolved this way - people spoke to their elders and rulers with sweeter tones and more agreeable melodies?

The ~ㅂ/습니다 conjugation could have been the ~ㄹ/즐보다 conjugation or something else, but perhaps that sounds less exalted or melodic.

I’m looking for psychological/neurological/linguistic research about these topics - please don’t speculate as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: While I believe the answer to this particular question is no, you may be interested in the broader linguistic concept (well, more of a hypothesis) of sound symbolism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism

Comment: There are only four voiced consonants in Korean: ㄴ, ㄹ, ㅁ, and ㅇ. The frequent use of these four sounds for the lyrics of children's songs indicates that such consonants can uplift children. Nonetheless, I am unsure whether they relate to honorifics, since even plenty of curse words have them.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to keep in mind is that (1) ㄴ and ㅁ are common consonants and (2) polite expressions are usually longer.  So, there's a good chance that a polite expression will contain either ㄴ or ㅁ.

But I highly doubt that polite expressions contain more ㄴ/ㅁ than average.  Let's just look at some regular-polite pairs:

> 나이 - 연세
>
> 말 - 말씀
>
> 주다 - 드리다
>
> 죽다 - 돌아가시다
>
> 아프다 - 편찮다
>
> 먹다 - 들다/드시다
>
> 있다 - 계시다
>
> 집 - 댁

The left side contains 15 characters, 1 ㄴ, and 2 ㅁ's.  The right side has 24 characters, 3 ㄴ's, and 2 ㅁ's.  Not much difference.

In conclusion, I don't think your theory is supported by data.